# Inserting a Model Property into an Img Element URL in Ember

Tags: model, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a Model with an `image_id` property. I have a View for that Model that contains an image element. I need to insert the id into the image element's `src` property to complete the URL of the image so that I'm effectively doing this:

```
<img src="news + newsItem.imageID + .jpg"></img>
```

My first attempt used a Handlebars helper:

```
<img src="news{{newsImageURL newsItem.imageID}}.jpg"></img>
```

But this also inserted Metamprph script tags around it:

```
<img url="&lt;script id='metamorph-10-start' type='text/x-placeholder'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;news/7.jpg&lt;script id='metamorph-10-end' type='text/x-placeholder'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;" alt="" class="content-image news-media" /></a>
```

So I've looked at using `bindAttr`, however as I need to transform the image_id value(by prepending and appending the rest of the path), this doesn't seem like a solution either.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are 2 possibilities:

1- Declare the image path as **computed property on your model**. If you don't like that, you could **declare it also in your ObjectController** backing this template:

The Template:

```
// until 1.0 RC7
<img {{bindAttr src="newsItem.imagePath"}}></img> 
// from 1.0 final (the above one is deprecated)
<img {{bind-attr src=newsItem.imagePath}}></img>
```

The Model:

```
App.NewsItem = DS.Model.extend({
  imageID: DS.attr('string'),
  imagePath: function() {
    return "/assets/news/"+this.get("imageID")+".jpg";
  }.property('imageID')
});
```

2-  If you do not need the binding in 1 (i guess your id won't change) and use the  `unbound helper`, which does not result in script tags:

```
<img src="news{{unbound newsItem.imageID}}.jpg"></img>
```

Comment: Note for 1.0.0 users: you should now write `{{bind-attr src=newsItem.imagePath}}`.

Comment: You left the quotes (which are also deprecated). See http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/08/29/ember-1-0-rc8.html (Bound Helpers).

Comment: Ok. Wasn't sure about this :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can make bindAttr reference a computed property and build your string there.