# Modify a property on a model before displaying to the page in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, properties, controller

On my server side I have a product model with a property called 'image' and it is the name of the image with it's extension, I'm using ember app kit and I'm placing my image in the public/assets folder and I want to reference that along with the file name so that it correctly displays the image on the page. So in my decent knowledge of ember I made an array controller (since I'm working with a set of products) and I took the property and just returned it with a string on the front referencing that path. But I'm getting nothing displayed to the page, not even a broken image.

I've placed this controller in controllers and called it products.js

```
var ProductsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
assetPath: function() {
    alert(this.get('image'));
    return '../assets/' + this.get('image');
}.property('image')
});

export default ProductsController;
```

and my template is just in templates and is called products.hbs and looks pretty basic

```
{{#each}}
    <div class="item">
        <h2>{{name}}</h2>
        <p>{{price}}</p>
        <p>{{image}}</p>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

First of why am I not getting anything when referencing this property? And second is this the "ember way" to do it or should it be done somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Just found this stack overflow (not sure why this didn't turn of the first time I searched)

[Inserting a Model Property into an Img Element URL in Ember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15624593/inserting-a-model-property-into-an-img-element-url-in-ember)

I forgot you could define these on the model as well.

so I just did this...

```
var Product = DS.Model.extend({
    ...
    image: DS.attr('string'),
    assetPath: function(){
        return "/assets/"+this.get('image');
    }.property('image')
});
```